NestJS validate null payload
I'm writing input validation for an event handler. The payload can be either an Order object or null. I need some help on how to allow null payloads in this setup, as they are currently rejected.
Here is my event handler:
class OrderDTO implements Order {
  @IsUUID()
  readonly id!: string;
}

@EventPattern('orders')
@UsePipes(
  new ValidationPipe({
    transform: true,
    whitelist: true,
    forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
    transformOptions: {
      enableImplicitConversion: true,
    },
  })
)
async handleOrderChange(
  @Payload() order: OrderDTO | null,
  @Ctx() context: KafkaContext
) {
  ...
}

I'm on nestjs 10.3.9 and class-validator 0.14.1

Your logic, namely, is to make OrderDTO optional. This is my proposed workaround. Therefore:

Try to make all properties inside class OrderDTO optional with the respective decorator @IsOptional()
In the uuid id property, you use '!' exclamation mark. This places it as necessary. It
Class OrderDTO implements Order. What is in there? You should be certain to have it all as optional, either from inheritance or another form.

